# FB.ui Facebook share doesn't work on posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I call the action,

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',

  // this works fine
  href: 'https://www.facebook.com/'

  // this works fine
  href: 'https://www.facebook.com/678506978/'

  // this doesn't
  href: 'https://www.facebook.com/678506978/posts/10152685321776979'
});
```

More specifically, the window pops up alright, but it's just a blank share window, with nothing beneath to show what I'm sharing. And after I clicked `Post to Facebook`, it doesn't appear in my timeline, unlike the former two.

My question: how to make sharing a post work?

Comment: File a bug with Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I had to make use of [the supposedly deprecated `feed` action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.1):

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'link of post',
  name: 'title of post',
  caption: 'description'
});
```

It works.

Comment: is there any problem with facebook share method it is giving blank post for me too because i want to share a post of a page as it is